# Write rows to CSV from SQL Server Trigger

Tags: sql

We need to write a trigger so that when rows inserted into a sql server table meeting certain conditions, they are then written to a windows OS flat file in CSV format.

Are there any commands short of running a xp_cmdshell that would allow us to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Any reason you wouldn't instead do a scheduled process with SSIS?

Depending on your transaction rate, I'd be hesistant to put this in a trigger since it means evaluations and possible export on every record entered. If you get a high frequency, you could shoot yourself in the foot...

Even if the transaction rate is fairly low, you could potentially still have problems like blocking/locking if the physical writes take long. You introduce several possible classes of errors (file i/o errors, write-fail means trigger fails means insert fails, etc.).

With a scheduled process you only take a hit on an infrequent basis and you don't potentially lock your table while the trigger is doing something external.

Comment: I agree regarding the trigger.  Regarding SSIS, there always seems to be some reason why it doesn't work for what we are trying to do.  It has left a bad taste in my mouth a few times.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I tacked that comment on. SSIS is good for somethings, not good for others. It has left me with a bitter aftertaste on several occassions. Typically pretty good with exports though.

Answer (score 1):

Use Bulk Copy Program (BCP) to create CSV files.   For example:

```
BCP master..sysobjects out c:\sysobjects.txt -c -t, -T –S<servername>
```

The basic format for the BCP command for creating a CSV file is as follows:

BCP  out

The switches used here are:

> -c Output in ASCII with the default field terminator (tab) and row terminator (crlf)"
>
> -t override the field terminator with ","
>
> -T use a trusted connection. -U & –P may be used for username/password
>
> -S connect to this server to execute the command

Here's another example:

```
declare @sql varchar(8000)

select @sql = 'bcp master..sysobjects out
c:\bcp\sysobjects.txt -c -t, -T -S'+ @@servername

exec master..xp_cmdshell @sql
```

Here's a description of how to use BCP:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx