# MSSQL2005 TRIGGER that creates a file on INSERT

Tags: sql-server-2005, csv, triggers, insert

I need an example of creating a trigger that would create a CSV file when a row is inserted into a table.

I have a table "Test" with fields "ID", "B" and "C".

I need a trigger that would create ID.CSV with ID;B;C content every time a row is inserted into a table.

Regards,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write rows to CSV from SQL Server Trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717294/write-rows-to-csv-from-sql-server-trigger)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by making a package in Sql server integration services and then call this package in your trigger.

check this link

http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/ssis-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-excel/

Comment: That is the solution. But i did not call SSIS package in a trigger. Rather i created a JOB on the server to execute it.